# SCSS compiling to CSS shows Error: Undefined mixin

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

please tell me what to do if you get this error? I'm new to SASS

[look of my style.SCSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nnEG.png)

[look of my style.CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCmat.png)

[look of my @mixins file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfbCp.png)

```
Error: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
17 │     @include font($size: 1.6rem, $height: 2.6rem, $weight: normal);
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  sass/base/_base.scss 17:5  @import
  sass/style.scss 1:9        root stylesheet
```

I found that after adding the node modules folder, styles stopped being written to the main style file style.css. In the SCSS file, all @import are registered. When I started rewriting styles via mixins, everything flew off and the CSS style file just zeroed out, there is now an error message and that's it… Even though before entering mixin and placeholders, when I just wrote styles for different elements in different files, everything was fine.

What can I do about it? I would appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Because you sent 3 parameters to 4 parameters mixin. You can set default $style value like this:

```
@mixin font($size, $height, $weight, $style: normal){
 ...
```

more information can be found in [the documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#optional-arguments).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your help! I've rewritten my code and this helped a lot. Stay healthy!

Comment: @priuet you're welcome. If was helpful please accept the my answer also.